# How to use additional files in NuGet package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm using clrzmq library via `NuGet`. It has additional file residing inside package:

```
content/libzmq.dll
```

I need to distribute it with my installer(wix), so I need to get that file from somewhere. If I add that dll file to the project using it, then every time new version of clrzmq arrives the path is changed and I need to fix it.

What is the proper way to copy that file to my project(or use it directly in wix)?

Answer (score 0):

The last stable release of the clrzmq NuGet package was July 2012, there have been no pre-release packages since November 2012. 
As it's not updated regularly, I'd keep things simple and continue to reference the additional dll as you are doing already.

Comment: That's how I reference it now from wix project: `Source="$(var.SolutionDir)packages\clrzmq.2.2.5\content\libzmq.dll"`. But I thought there is some mechanism in NuGet to cope with changing package version.